# Image on left side needs to be continuous in PDF generated

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i have a PDF to be generated with 6 reports PER page.
i need a left side image on the whole PDF.

LIKE FOR SAY

```
> PDF
>        page 1 
image1
image1   report
image1    
>        page 2 
image1
image1   report
image1     
>        page 3 
image1
image1   report
image1
```

i tried using the following ways but did not get the desired result

1. simply inserted the image using Right click -> Insert -> Image.set the size of image as 1*3 as required.
2. simply used the background image property of SSRS but the size is not 1 * 3 as i wanted.

problem:
i am not getting continuous 3 images on each report in the 6 pages in my PDF.
what i am getting is something like this

```
> PDF
>        page 1 
image1
image1   report
image1    
>        page 2 

         report
image1     
>        page 3 

         report
image1
```

i really hope i made myself clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I will post as an answer. I would suggest using the image as a background. As I see, you want the image to repeat 3 times in EVERY page of the report, that's a background. Use a image editor, edit the image like you want to look in every page and then set it as background. The next step is setting the size of the image so it matches your Report.